# How can I get backwards compatibility on my local machine so it can run an older opensource project locally?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dependencies, data-generation

I am trying to set-up an opensource project called [accessmaps](https://github.com/AccessMap/accessmap) to see and understand how it actually works. The problem is that this project was created several years ago and some packages are not supported anymore.

To be more specific, in the [documentation](https://github.com/AccessMap/accessmap#pedestrian-network-data) of the project they say that in order to make it work, you have to generate some data using another [repository](https://github.com/OpenSidewalks/opensidewalks-data). The problem is that when I am trying to use the commands of this [repo](https://github.com/OpenSidewalks/opensidewalks-data), I come across this kind of error:

```
[Thu Jul  6 13:14:03 2023]
Error in rule draw_sidewalks:
    jobid: 0
    output: interim/redrawn/sidewalks.geojson, interim/redrawn/streets.geojson

RuleException:
TypeError in line 496 of /data/cities/seattle/Snakefile:
'MultiPoint' object is not subscriptable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2326, in run_wrapper
  File "/data/cities/seattle/Snakefile", line 496, in __rule_draw_sidewalks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sidewalkify/draw/draw.py", line 39, in draw_sidewalks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sidewalkify/draw/trim.py", line 36, in trim
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sidewalkify/draw/trim.py", line 61, in ixn_and_trim
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 568, in _callback
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 554, in cached_or_run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2357, in run_wrapper
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

The build is split in 24 jobs and when it hits job 11 it crashes showing the error above.

The requirements file of the project contains these packages inside:

```
-e git://github.com/dezhin/osmread.git@d8d3fe5edd15fdab9526ea7a100ee6c796315663#egg=osmread
crossify==0.1.4
esridump==1.7.0
geopandas==0.4.0
rasterio==1.0a12
requests==2.21
scipy==1.0.1
sidewalkify==0.2.1
snakemake==4.8.0
```

I am also using

```
numpy 1.19.5
```

as the project does not support numpy versions>1.20.

I tried to rollback a few versions on some packages (like numpy) but it did not actually work. I also tried to install the latest versions of some dependencies that were deprecated but it was also a dead end.

Comment: We use virtual environment on pythons. And one of the feature you can set an environment with older version. It is really the recommend way: always use a virtual environment for every project.

Comment: I am using a virtual environment with python3.8 venv. The problem probably lies with the other dependencies as I mentioned on the question.

Comment: Create a new virtual environment. In any case, I recommend *conda* (anaconda) which can handle very easily different version of Python (also python2). I think it may be easy to handle environments (note: conda was founded by primary contributors of numpy and scipy, to solve python scientific data problems, which seems your case). In any case (with all environment managements): one environment for each project and requirements (so you may have many environment for same project, if you need to test old (or future) libraries)

Comment: Using MyBinder to set the configuration files to match what you need may be another way to go if the sessions you get provide enough computation power to do what you need. See [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) about the use of `requirements.txt`. You may need to set it to use an old Python using `runtime.txt`, too.